# Bluemix MobileFirst 8.0 Service "Initializing..."

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I have a MobileFirst Server 8.0 deployed in Bluemix as a CF app.  Under Services I click on my MF Servcice and launch the "Service Details" screen. Under the Overview section, I see the "Starting the server" item with the following message

"This can take up to 10 minutes to complete You'll be able to use your server in a while"  Initializing Server

This message never goes.  It is in this state forever even though I am able to click on the "Launch Console" and go to the console and work with my apps and adapters.

Everything is fine except this annoying misleading message.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. I've pinged the dev team and asked for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood this is a visual bug, causing the banner to not disappear after the service has been initialized and the server started.

1. Try creating a new service instance and see if it goes away
2. Either way, if the server is functioning, you may disregard this.

This will be investigated anyway to make sure this won't happen.